# Double Integrals & Expected Value Monte Carlo Method

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation, monte-carlo

**Tell me if I'm wrong**

Let $\Omega = [a,b]\times[c,d]\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, then

$$
\iint_\Omega \frac{1}{(x+y)^2}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}y=\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}y\tag{1}
$$

is the double integral of $\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}$ over $\Omega$. I need to approximate the double integral above using the Expected Value Monte Carlo Method over $\Omega = [1,2]\times[3,4]$.

Let $\zeta:x\mapsto X = \zeta(x)$ a discrete pdf in $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{a}^{b}\xi(x)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x\right] = \frac{\mathrm{abs}(a-b)}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\xi\left[a+\mathrm{abs}(a-b)X_i\right]\tag{2}
$$

give an aproximation of a mono-dimensional integral of a given function $\xi(x)$ over $[a,b]$. My question is—if what I said it's all correct, how can I modify the $(2)$ to handle a double integral?

**Java Implementation**

```
class doubleIntMonteCarlo
{
    private static double sum = 0D;
    private static double xSum = 0D;
    private static double ySum = 0D;

    private static double f(double x, double y)
    {
        return 1 / Math.pow( x + y , 2 );
    }

    public static double doubleIntMonteCarlo(double a, double b, double c, double d, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            xSum = a + c + (b - a) * Math.random();
            ySum = (d - c) * Math.random();

            sum += f(xSum, ySum);

            //System.out.println(xSum + "  " + ySum + "  " + sum);
        }
        return sum / n;
    }
}

public class MonteCarloIntegration 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(doubleIntMonteCarlo.doubleIntMonteCarlo(1, 2, 3, 4, 10000000));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please modify $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2 = [1,2]\times[3,4]$, which is certainly not what you want to say.

Comment: @Did I'm sorry, it's better now?

Comment: Sure--except that I fail to understand why $[1,2]\times[3,4]$ disappeared.

Comment: @Did lol to be compatible and more clear with the snippet below! I'll fix this thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generate $(U_n)$ i.i.d. uniform in $[0,1]$ and consider
$$
I_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(4+U_{2k-1}+U_k)^2}.
$$
Then $I_n$ converges almost surely to your integral and the error between $I_n$ and the integral is typically of order $1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: This addresses the original version of the question, which was considering $[a,b]\times[c,d]=[1,2]\times[3,4]$. For a general product of intervals, consider the factor $(b-a)(d-c)$ and replace $4+U_{2k-1}+U_{2k}$ by $a+c+(b-a)U_{2k-1}+(d-c)U_{2k}$.

Comment: Please, can you clarify what you mean with $U_n$? I'm not saying that you are not clear, I mean to me. Should I generate $n$ random values in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yeah--actually $2n$ values but this is the idea.

Comment: Take a look at my Java implementation, I can't understand why it converges when the domain of integration is $\Omega = [1,2]\times[3,4]$ while it doesn't if I change it.

Comment: For which Omega does it fail to converge?

Comment: I think I don't understand the meaning of the subscripts you've used in $U_{2k-1}$ and $U_k$. If I run the code above I get $0.04082270681150155$ which is very precise. But if I use $[1, 2]\times[1, 4]$ for example, I get $0.07435977925390848$ Vs $0.223144$ (actual value)

Comment: The random variables $U_k$ used to generate $I_n$ are $2n$ random values independent and uniform in $[0,1]$. Obviously, the values you cite indicate a problem in the implementation.